# Flutter not diplaying anything when i run the code in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

it is supposed to be showing "hello world" in blue color but when i run the code it does not show anything . only thing that is displayed is  the project title and nothing else
can someone tell what's the problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHUwH.png)

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World!',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue, // set the text color to blue
          ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }}`
```

it is supposed to be showing "hello world" in blue color but when i run the code it does not show anything . only thing that is displayed is  the project title and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

You are using Firebase on Flutter web. You need to make some changes to the `web/index.html` file before running your app. You must import the Firebase Javascript SDK and initialize Firebase.

For a more detailed explanation, please check out the official Firebase documentation.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/manual-installation/web/

Or because this one could be outdated take a look at the updated setup instructions:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=web